# XML parsing using LINQ: what is the best way to get value of nearby node

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq

I am trying to parse the following XML:

```
<bs:School>
    <bs:Class number="1">
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Male</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Jason</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Male</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Danny</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Female</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Jessica</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Male</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Will</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Female</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Betty</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
    </bs:Class>
    <bs:Class number="2">
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Male</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Sean</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Female</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Jessica</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
        <bs:Student>
            <bs:Gender>Male</bs:Gender>
            <bs:Name>Dexter</bs:Name>
        </bs:Student>
    </bs:Class>
</bs:School>
```

How can I select all of the male students names?

I have tried using the following LINQ query:

```
 var resources = from c in doc.Descendants("Gender")
                 where (c.Value.ToString().Contains("Male"))
                 select c.Parent.Descendants("Name");
```

It always returns an empty object.

Comment: you are not using the `bs` namespace in your query

Comment: To get an answer add you namespace declaration in xml

Comment: Yeah I am, It is not the complete xml - just the important section, I am looking for the problem in my query - I was able to get the name when I tried to get all of the students name using another query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I've added namespace declaration in the root node `xmlns:bs = ""MyNamespace""`. So in my example root node looks like `<bs:School xmlns:bs = "MyNamespace">` instead of  `<bs:School>`

```
var xml = //your xml

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace bs = "MyNamespace";

string[] malesNames = 
                doc.Descendants(bs + "Student")
                   .Where(stud => stud.Element(bs + "Gender").Value == "Male")
                   .Select(stud => stud.Element(bs + "Name").Value)
                   .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, malesNames));
```

will print:

```
Jason 
Danny 
Will 
Sean 
Dexter
```

---

Namespace agnostic solution to search for names of male students is given below:

```
doc.Descendants()
   .Where(node => node.Name.LocalName == "Student")
   .Where(node => node.Elements().First(child => child.Name.LocalName == "Gender").Value == "Male") 
   .Select(node => node.Elements().First(child => child.Name.LocalName == "Name").Value);
```

---

Feel free to extract common pieces of query into separate extension methods, for example:

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static XElement GetFirstChild(this XElement node, string nodeName)
    {
        return node.Elements().First(child => child.Name.LocalName == nodeName);
    }
}
```

now you can:

```
doc.Descendants()
   .Where(node => node.Name.LocalName == "Student")
   .Where(node => node.GetFirstChild("Gender").Value == "Male") 
   .Select(node => node.GetFirstChild("Name").Value);
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without knowing the namespace before run time?

Comment: @user1322801 That doesn't make much sense, namespace shouldn't change willy-nilly. But if you do know the namespace at runtime, you can decide what will `XNamespace` contain at runtime.

Comment: @user1322801, You can find the the namespace by just checking the `Descendants().First()` and extracting the namespace from the property of the result